# When is the 2-category of Commutative Monoids (Co)complete?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, limits-and-colimits

Let $C$ be a strict 2-category which is bicomplete (has all 2-(co)limits). Assume further that $C$ is symmetric monoidal. Denote by $CMon(C)$ its 2-category of commutative monoids. When is $CMon(C)$ (co)complete?

Comment: I don't know anything about 2 (co)limits, but for regular (co)limits, note that limits are always computed in C, and in order for CMon(C) to have colimits it should be the case that the forgetful functor $U:CMon(C) \to C$ preserves filtered colimits (this is equivalent to the left adjoint $Sym$ preserving filtered colimits). Check out Schwede-Shipley *Algebras and Modules* or Batanin-Berger paper on polynomial monads.